# Creating multiple statuses of a file in git

Tags: git, serena

I use git for Version control. I would like to maintain the status of a file like committed, approved to test, approved to preprod etc., so that when the code is pulled in respective environment eg: test, all the files marked as approved to test needs to be pulled. Serena dimensions CM has this feature. How can I achieve the same in git.

Answer (score 0):

You can create various [branches](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v1/Git-Branching-What-a-Branch-Is) for different cases. Creating branches will help you maintain different state of your project where each branch can represent preproduction, test, etc stages.

This way you can test your changes in test branch, then move to production (representing in different branch). A very good and clear article can be found [here](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/using-branches/)